# node file system module rename methode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to change a file name using rename method from file system library the file name changed but I get an error like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.renameSync("./name.js", "anothername.js");
```

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename './changed.js' -> 'another.js'
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:614:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lenovo/Desktop/test.js:2:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

Comment: The error is clear isn't it?. You're trying to rename a file that does not exist. If you want more help, post the directory structure, and the exact code you're using.

Comment: the file actually exists and its name changed but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Then it doesnt exist in that folder, show the file structure, and where you're calling the script from. You usually want to use `path.join(__dirname, 'name.js')` or add some `..` if it's not on the same folder as the script.

Comment: I don't know why but the fileName is changing when I'm saving the code I not using nodemon or sth like that and that's because I getting the error